# Promises and chained calls

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript, promise

I've realized JS callback hell and I started looking into Promises libraries.
After reading some articles I decided to start with [BluebirdJS](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird). I didn't realise how to properly use them yet, because documentation written with API examples, not real usage.

I have two files (NodeJS environment):

```
#monitor.js
Promise = require("bluebird")
class Monitor
  constructor: (@api) ->

  getServerInfo: ->
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      @api.query("messages.getLongPollServer", { use_ssl: 1}).then(
        (result) =>
          @key = result.response.key
          @server = result.response.server
          @ts = result.response.ts

          resolve(@)

        reject
      )
    )

  printDetails: ->
    console.log(@key, @server, @ts)

module.exports = Monitor

#app.js
Api = require("./api")
Monitor = require("./monitor")

api = new Api("6de61129da290c3edf9c699ad25638156266e7b6bdbcc00407efb630e5c62f2d4c71974c7bdba52a03dbd")

monitor = new Monitor(api)

monitor.getServerInfo().then((monitor) -> monitor.printDetails())
```

What I wanted to achieve is something like this:

```
monitor.getServerInfo().then().printDetails()
```

because `getServerInfo` runs asynchronously.

Am I using promises correctly?

Comment: what is Api? Why are you creating new Promise when api.query already returns a promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use explicit returns in CoffeeScript unless you have to (and you don't here)
2. CoffeeScript may do automatic comma insertion, but I certainly didn't right away (i.e. add a comma yourself, right before `reject` - anything to make it easier to read)

Anyway: You can't get this code

```
monitor.getServerInfo().then().printDetails()
```

because that would be *synchronous*, not asynchronous. The interpreter would have to wait in the middle of the chain before it could call `printDetails`. And it doesn't wait - that's the point of asynchronicity.

And that's why `then()` always returns a promise object (and nothing else), because it can return that right away without any waiting.

So your current code

```
monitor.getServerInfo().then((monitor) -> monitor.printDetails())
```

is the way to do it. Of course, it doesn't make much sense to have a `printDetails` method in your `Monitor`, if it doesn't always work. Right now, you can just call

```
(new Monitor(api)).printDetails()
```

and get

```
undefined, undefined, undefined
```

printed. Or, if you just happened to call it *after* the API query has run, `printDetails` will suddenly print actual values. The method is almost random at that point because there's nothing guaranteeing that things happen in the right order.

I'd just skip the `Monitor` class entirely, since it's not really contributing much - at least not right now. But, given the name "monitor", I imagine the point is to get the server info, so you can then set up a polling system of some kind.

In that case, you could make a factory method that returns its product via a promise:

```
Promise = require "bluebird"

class Monitor
  constructor: (@server, @key, @ts) ->
    # I don't know if a Monitor instance needs an api object
    # for anything. If it does, add it as an argument to
    # this constructor

  startPolling: ->
    # ... or something

  stopPolling: -> 
    # ... or something

  printDetails: ->
    console.log @server, @key, @ts

# factory function
Monitor.create = (api) ->
  # internal function that actually runs the query
  createMonitor = (resolveCallback, rejectCallback) ->
    success = (data) ->
      {server, key, ts} = data.response # CoffeeScript destructuring
      resolveCallback new Monitor(server, key, ts) # also pass in the api obj, if needed

    api.query("messages.getLongPollServer", use_ssl: 1).then success, rejectCallback

  # return a promise that'll resolve with 
  # a new Monitor instance (or fail,
  # presumably with an error of some sort)
  new Promise createMonitor

module.exports = Monitor
```

If you already have the `server`, `key` and `ts` values from somewhere, then great; just call `new Monitor(server, key, ts)` and you're done.

But if you don't, you can do this:

```
Api     = require("./api")
Monitor = require("./monitor")

api = new Api("6de61....")

success = (monitor) -> monitor.printDetails() # or whatever else you need
failure = (args...) -> console.warn args...

Monitor.create(api).then success, failure
```

This is basically turning the process inside out: Instead of instantiating a `Monitor` object, and making *it* fetch the data it needs, the factory method is doing the fetching, and only creating the instance when it's time to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Bluebird has the concept of Promisification that converts any library into a Promise. Maybe it did not exist at the time the chosen answer was written, but I wanted to add this so people coming into this answer should look into that option before anything else. You can use this without changing your existing library code.

https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var Monitor = Promise.promisifyAll(require('Monitor'));
```

Then something like:

```
//using getServerInfoAsync to show that you could have written 
//getServerInfo without returning a Promise, as if it were to be used as a callback
monitor.getServerInfoAsync().then(monitor.printDetailsAsync)
```